# Can't open semaphore from another process

Tags: c, winapi, semaphore

I'm creating a global semaphore object in a process like this:

`CreateSemaphore(NULL, 1, 1, "Global\\bitmap");`

now, when I'm trying to open it in a child process (it's a special case of "another process", it's not going to be a child that opens the semaphore created) like this:

`bitmapSem = OpenSemaphore(NULL, TRUE, "Global\\bitmap");`

the `bitmapSem` variable equals `NULL` and I'm getting error 5 (ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED) from `GetLastError()`.

Any ideas?

Comment: do yo umean a `fork()` -ed child?

Comment: The create uses `Global\\bitmap` and the open uses just `bitmap`. Should the open not also be `Global\\bitmap` as the default namespace may not by `Global`?

Comment: Ahh, sorry, tried both - editing now.

Comment: @Adrian you could say, I used `CreateProcess()` (coz it's win)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I must add a clarification to other answers, and a security warning.

First, passing NULL as the `lpSemaphoreAttributes` argument to `::CreateSemaphore()` does *not* mean no access to anybody; rather, it means that default access control will be assigned. [MSDN is crystal clear on that](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682438%28v=vs.85%29.aspx): *If this parameter is NULL, the semaphore gets a default security descriptor. The ACLs in the default security descriptor for a semaphore come from the primary or impersonation token of the creator.*

Normally, the semaphore can be opened and used by the same user identity. So, if the semaphore is shared by processes running in the same interactive session, or under the same service identity, it may be opened by another process even if created with the default security descriptor. As @hmjd already noted, you must always explicitly call out the right that you want to assert on the semaphore: `SYNCHRONIZE|SEMAPHORE_MODIFY_STATE` allows both waiting on and releasing it.

Second of all, a word of caution. By granting Everyone full access to the semaphore, as it was suggested above, a security hole for a DoS attack is potentially created. You should consider whether you want arbitrary processes to be able to grab and release the semaphore. Is it intended for unrestricted public use? It is always a good practice to assign minimal, narrowly permitting ACLs to objects. Using [SDDL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379567%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is probably the easiest way to encode a security descriptor, albeit the script itself is not very readable.

Comment: Thanks a million! hmjd's answer was almost there, but what made it work was the added right `SEMAPHORE_MODIFY_STATE` (it's needed to enable a process to release a semaphore i think). So I actually needed both rights: `SYNCHRONIZE|SEMAPHORE_MODIFY_STATE`.

Answer (score 8):

The first argument to [`OpenSemaphore()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684326%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is documented as:

> dwDesiredAccess [in]
>
> The access to the semaphore object. The function fails if the security descriptor of the specified object does not permit the requested access for the calling process. For a list of access rights, see Synchronization Object Security and Access Rights.

In the posted code `NULL` is specified: which is not documented as having a special meaning. Change to one of the access rights documented at [Synchronization Object Security and Access Rights](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686670%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

```
bitmapSem = OpenSemaphore(SYNCHRONIZE, TRUE, "Global\\bitmap");
```

EDIT:

To create a security descriptor that would grant access to `Everyone` try the following (untested) code:

```
/* Create a security descriptor that has an an empty DACL, to
   grant access to 'Everyone'. */
SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR sd;
if (0 == InitializeSecurityDescriptor(&sd,
                                      SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR_REVISION) ||
    0 == SetSecurityDescriptorDacl(&sd,
                                   TRUE,
                                   (PACL)0,
                                   FALSE))
{
    /* Failed to create security descriptor. */
}
else
{
    SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES sa;
    sa.nLength              = sizeof(sa);
    sa.lpSecurityDescriptor = &sd;
    sa.bInheritHandle       = FALSE;

    HANDLE sh = CreateSemaphore(&sa, 1, 1, "Global\\bitmap");
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I've read the docs - but sadly there're no examples, and they lead to other docs :(. An example or at least a snippet of  the struct that I should be passing in order to make the semaphore accessible would be very appreciated.

Comment: The first argument to OpenSemaphore() is not a struct, but a bitmask of options. Updated answer with example.

Comment: Note that you shouldn't need to mess with Security Descriptors unless you want a process _run by another user_ to be able to open the semaphore. Windows security is (mostly) user-centric, not process centric, so any resource created by a process running as some user can be accessed by any other process running as that same user (assuming the other process is in the same place as that resource - eg. on the same machine, session, etc.).

Comment: @BrendanMcK, I agree. From the OP's question he did state child process and you would assume this was the same user, though he could be using `CreateProcessAsUser()`, and the child process is described as _special_, whatever that means, so I was unsure if it was the same user.

Comment: Thanks for the elaborate example. Going to try it today.

Comment: Thanks for useful example. I am working on code that can either run as a service, or as a console app. When running as a service, the semaphores are created fine with a null security descriptor. When running as a console app, the creation was failing. Adding your example of the security descriptor caused the createSemaphore of the console app to succeed, so I'm a happy camper.

Answer (score 0):

> lpSemaphoreAttributes [in, optional]
>   A pointer to a
>   SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES structure. If this parameter is NULL, the handle
>   cannot be inherited by child processes.

Pass an `LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES` with an empty DACL and the `bInheritHandle` member set appropriately as the 1st argument.

An example in VB would be:

```
'Setup the security descriptor
InitializeSecurityDescriptor SecurityDescriptor, SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR_REVISION
SetSecurityDescriptorDacl SecurityDescriptor, 1, ByVal 0, 0 'Dacl is present and empty

'Setup the security attributes
SecurityAttributes.nLength = Len(SecurityAttributes)
SecurityAttributes.lpSecurityDescriptor = VarPtr(SecurityDescriptor)
SecurityAttributes.bInheritHandle = False
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It's not going to be a child process every time though. I need a general solution. In any case, why would a global semaphore won't be available to all?

Comment: Almost, you need to create a valid Security descriptor with no ACLs which essentially means no restrictions. A NULL SA structure means no access.

Comment: @Deanna thanks, I can't seem to find a valid example of code though :(

Comment: I've updated Alex's answer with a (VB6) sample but it's easy enough to convert to any other language.